# How to get rid of a HUGE space between rows in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I'm entering data into an excel spreadsheet sometimes all of a sudden there is a huge space/gap between rows. For example, I'm entering info into line 396 and then after 396 there's a huge white space that I have to scroll down through in order to get to 397. I have no idea where the huge white space came from or how to get rid of it.

Comment: Try this once,, select TOP Left notch of the Sheet & from HOME tab got to Cell , Format,, Row Height ,,, or check the Enter Button may it's been sticky now !!

Comment: *after 396 .. huge white space .. to 397* Does you mean that 396/397 is a value inserted into some column? If so simply sort your data by this column...

Comment: This isn't really an answerable question as it stands. Are you manually entering info, or have you copied and pasted something (that presumably includes lots of line breaks or other extra characters)? What exactly are you doing when this happens 'all of a sudden'? What happens when you delete the offending row? Can you repeat the process that makes this problem occur? Help us understand what's happening.